# Help with class and derived class processing

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment that uses a base class "bankAccount" and two derived classes "checkingAccount" and "savingsAccount". I am currently bewildered at the output I am getting. all of the ending balances are ending up negative. Could anyone take a look at my code and see if they spot why this might be? I presume I am doing something wrong in the process function of the derived class "checkingAccount". "savingsAccount" process function will be similar I just haven't made it yet cause the first one isn't working.  thanks!

**header:**

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

class bankAccount
{
    public:
    bankAccount();
    void setAccountInfo(int accountNumTemp, double balanceTemp);
    void prePrint(char accountType);
    void process(char accountType, char transactionTypeTemp, int amountTemp, int j);
    void postPrint();

    private:
    int accountNumber;
    double balance;
};

class checkingAccount: public bankAccount
{
    public:
    void prePrint(int accountNumber, char accountType, double checkingBalance);
    checkingAccount();
    double checkingAccount:: process(char transactionTypeTemp, int amountTemp, int j, double checkingBalance);
    /*applyTansaction();
    applyInterest();*/

    private:
    float interestRate;
    int minimumBalance;
    float serviceCharge;

};

class savingsAccount: public bankAccount
{
    public:
    void prePrint(int savingsAccountNumber, char accountType, double savingsBalance);
    savingsAccount();
   /* applyTansaction();
    applyInterest();*/

    private:
    float interestRate;
};


#endif // HEADER_H_INCLUDED
```

**class Implementation:**

```
#include "header.h"

bankAccount:: bankAccount()
{
    accountNumber = 0;
    balance = 0;
}

void bankAccount:: setAccountInfo(int accountNumTemp, double balanceTemp)
{
    accountNumber = accountNumTemp;
    balance = balanceTemp;
}

void bankAccount:: prePrint(char accountType)
{
    if(accountType == 'C')
    {
        int checkingAccountNumber = accountNumber;
        double checkingBalance = balance;
        checkingAccount ca;
        ca.prePrint(checkingAccountNumber, accountType, checkingBalance);
    }
    else if (accountType == 'S')
    {
        int savingsAccountNumber = accountNumber;
        double savingsBalance = balance;
        savingsAccount sa;
        sa.prePrint(savingsAccountNumber, accountType, savingsBalance);
    }


}

void bankAccount:: process(char accountType, char transactionTypeTemp, int amountTemp, int j)
{
        double checkingBalance;
        checkingAccount ca;
        //savingsAccount sa;

        if (accountType == 'C')
        {
            checkingBalance = balance;
            balance = ca.process(transactionTypeTemp, amountTemp, j, checkingBalance);
        }
        /*else if (accountType == 'S')
        {
            savingsBalance = balance;
            sa.process(transactionTypeTemp, amountTemp, j, savingsBalance)
        }*/

}

void bankAccount:: postPrint()
{
   cout << "Balance after processing: " << balance << endl;
}

checkingAccount:: checkingAccount()
{
    interestRate = .02;
    minimumBalance = 500;
    serviceCharge = 20;
}

void checkingAccount:: prePrint(int checkingAccountNumber, char accountType, double checkingBalance)
{
    cout << "Account Number:" << checkingAccountNumber << " account type:" << accountType << " Starting Balance:" << checkingBalance << endl;
}

double checkingAccount:: process(char transactionTypeTemp, int amountTemp, int j, double checkingBalance)
{
  if (transactionTypeTemp == 'D')
        {
            checkingBalance = checkingBalance + amountTemp;
            checkingBalance = (checkingBalance * interestRate);
        }
  else if (transactionTypeTemp == 'W')
        {
            if ((checkingBalance = checkingBalance - amountTemp) < 0)
            {
            cout << "error: transaction number" << j + 1 << " never occured due to insufficent funds." << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                checkingBalance = checkingBalance - amountTemp;
                if(checkingBalance < minimumBalance) //if last transaction brought the balance below minimum balance
                {
                    checkingBalance = (checkingBalance - serviceCharge); //apply service charge
                    checkingBalance = (checkingBalance * interestRate);  //apply interest

                }
                else // if last transaction did not bring the balance below minimum balance
                {
                    checkingBalance = (checkingBalance * interestRate); //apply interest without service charge
                }
            }
        }

        return checkingBalance;
}

savingsAccount:: savingsAccount()
{
    interestRate = .04;
}

void savingsAccount:: prePrint(int savingsAccountNumber, char accountType, double savingsBalance)
{
    cout << "Account Number:" << savingsAccountNumber << " account type:" << accountType << " Starting Balance:" << savingsBalance << endl;
}
```

**main:**

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    int numberOfAccounts, accountNumTemp, transactionNum, amountTemp;
    double balanceTemp;
    char discard, accountType, transactionTypeTemp;
    bankAccount ba;

    cout << "Processing account data..." << endl;

    inFile.open("Bank.txt");

    if (!inFile)
    {
        for  (int a = 0; a < 20; a++)
            cout  << endl;
        cout << "Cannot open the input file."
             << endl;
            return 1;
    }

    inFile >> numberOfAccounts;
    inFile.get(discard);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAccounts; i++)
    {
            inFile >> accountNumTemp >> accountType >> balanceTemp >> transactionNum;
            inFile.get(discard);
            ba.setAccountInfo(accountNumTemp, balanceTemp);
            ba.prePrint(accountType);

            for (int j = 0; j < transactionNum; j++)
            {
                inFile >> transactionTypeTemp >> amountTemp;
                inFile.get(discard);
                ba.process(accountType, transactionTypeTemp, amountTemp, j);
            }

            ba.postPrint();

    }


    inFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of code to wade through to help with a homework assignment - Have you tried debugging your code? at what point does what you expect to happen deviate from what does happen? double-check that line and the variables used in it. Also, there are a lot of places in your code where you repeat lines needlessly - eg  `int checkingAccountNumber = accountNumber;` and `double checkingBalance = balance;` - these lines could be moved above the if statement, reducing your code and making it easier to maintain.
Learn about [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY)

Comment: @basiclife, Yea, I know its a stretch someone will dig through all that code and figure out the problem. Just thought I would post it all tonight in case someone is bored and can provide some pointers before I start working on it again tomorrow. :P

Comment: 1) This code doesn't compile, so it's not actually the code that's giving you trouble, 2) you haven't included the data (`Bank.txt`) that gives rise to the error, and most important of all, 3) this code is much too complicated. You have two derived classes, *both of which are malfunctioning*. Did you write the second class before or after you noticed the error? Never add to code that doesn't work. Now see how much you can simplify this code and still get the error, then see if the cause of the problem leaps out at you, and if not then edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm actually working for a bank, so I couldn't leave this. :-)

Adding to your problems:

```
if (transactionTypeTemp == 'D')
{
     checkingBalance = checkingBalance + amountTemp;
     checkingBalance = (checkingBalance * interestRate);
}
```

This actually **only** leaves the interest on the account!

Also, a real bank doesn't compute the interest when you do a deposit, but on fixed days like once a month or once a year. The interest you get (or pay) also depends on the number of days the account has had a certain balance.

```
if ((checkingBalance = checkingBalance - amountTemp) < 0)
{
    cout << "error: transaction number" << j + 1 << " never occured due to insufficent funds." << endl;
}
```

Despite the text written to cout, the transaction really **has** occurred, as `=` assigns a new value to Balance! Perhaps you should just compare the balance and the amount?

You then repeat the invalid interest calculations again in the `else` part.

Comment: +1 I think there are a couple of other issues in there ad the architecture needs a tweak but well done spotting the above.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous issues. I'll mention one. You one base class (bank accounnt) and two derived classes (checking account and savings account).  You then have methods (the process method) within the base class which instantiate objects from the derived classes. This isn't good. I think a re-review of deriving classes will help you solve your problem.